# output of /proc/xx/map for /bin/bash

Tags: linux

I am on a 64bit debian (Linux alexDesktop 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 15 15:39:52 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux).

I am trying to understand the memory maps in linux.
/bin/bash is my example.

`ps` output:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
23921 pts/48   00:00:00 bash
29431 pts/48   00:00:00 ps
```

`cat /proc/23921/maps` output:

```
00400000-004d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 4350017                            /bin/bash
006d9000-006e2000 rw-p 000d9000 08:02 4350017                            /bin/bash
006e2000-006e8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
00fac000-01001000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f47d6a4c000-7f47d6a57000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 887361                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7f47d6a57000-7f47d6c56000 ---p 0000b000 08:02 887361                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7f47d6c56000-7f47d6c57000 r--p 0000a000 08:02 887361                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7f47d6c57000-7f47d6c58000 rw-p 0000b000 08:02 887361                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
7f47d6c58000-7f47d6c62000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 887373                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7f47d6c62000-7f47d6e61000 ---p 0000a000 08:02 887373                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7f47d6e61000-7f47d6e62000 r--p 00009000 08:02 887373                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7f47d6e62000-7f47d6e63000 rw-p 0000a000 08:02 887373                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
7f47d6e63000-7f47d6e78000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 887371                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
7f47d6e78000-7f47d7077000 ---p 00015000 08:02 887371                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
7f47d7077000-7f47d7078000 r--p 00014000 08:02 887371                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
7f47d7078000-7f47d7079000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 887371                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
7f47d7079000-7f47d707b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f47d707b000-7f47d7082000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 887363                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7f47d7082000-7f47d7281000 ---p 00007000 08:02 887363                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7f47d7281000-7f47d7282000 r--p 00006000 08:02 887363                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7f47d7282000-7f47d7283000 rw-p 00007000 08:02 887363                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
7f47d7283000-7f47d72a8000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 887309                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f47d72a8000-7f47d74a7000 ---p 00025000 08:02 887309                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f47d74a7000-7f47d74ab000 r--p 00024000 08:02 887309                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f47d74ab000-7f47d74ac000 rw-p 00028000 08:02 887309                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
7f47d74ac000-7f47d762c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 887367                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f47d762c000-7f47d782c000 ---p 00180000 08:02 887367                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f47d782c000-7f47d7830000 r--p 00180000 08:02 887367                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f47d7830000-7f47d7831000 rw-p 00184000 08:02 887367                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f47d7831000-7f47d7836000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f47d7836000-7f47d7838000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 887360                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f47d7838000-7f47d7a38000 ---p 00002000 08:02 887360                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f47d7a38000-7f47d7a39000 r--p 00002000 08:02 887360                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f47d7a39000-7f47d7a3a000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 887360                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f47d7a3a000-7f47d7a5b000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 887311                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9
7f47d7a5b000-7f47d7c5a000 ---p 00021000 08:02 887311                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9
7f47d7c5a000-7f47d7c5b000 r--p 00020000 08:02 887311                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9
7f47d7c5b000-7f47d7c5c000 rw-p 00021000 08:02 887311                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9
7f47d7c5c000-7f47d7c7c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 887370                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7f47d7e6c000-7f47d7e70000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f47d7e79000-7f47d7e7b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f47d7e7b000-7f47d7e7c000 r--p 0001f000 08:02 887370                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7f47d7e7c000-7f47d7e7d000 rw-p 00020000 08:02 887370                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7f47d7e7d000-7f47d7e7e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff4bc2a000-7fff4bc3f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff4bc41000-7fff4bc42000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

can someone explain why the first four lines of the output is different with the other?
the address there is 32bit address, not 64bit.

Answer (score 3):

This output is generated by [`show_map_vma`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=show_map_vma) in [`fs/task_mmu.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/task_mmu.c#L253). The relevant line of code is:

```c
seq_printf(m, "%08lx-%08lx %c%c%c%c %08llx %02x:%02x %lu ",
                start,
                end,
                flags & VM_READ ? 'r' : '-',
                flags & VM_WRITE ? 'w' : '-',
                flags & VM_EXEC ? 'x' : '-',
                flags & VM_MAYSHARE ? 's' : 'p',
                pgoff,
                MAJOR(dev), MINOR(dev), ino);
```

So you can see that the standard `printf`-style formatting specifies `%08lx`, meaning a minimum of 8 hex digits, prefixed with zeros. Any numbers larger than this (aka 64-bit values) will simply print more digits.

---

Issuing the command `readelf -l $(which bash)` will list its program headers. You'll see that the `bash` ELF file has been linked such that its `.text` (and other) sections are loaded up at the virtual address 0x400000.  The output of `/proc/[pid]/maps` is simply reflecting this.